# Using angle of line as shape rotation degree in Figma

Tags: shapes, figma

I want to match the rotation degree of the grey box to the angle of the black shape so it's neatly aligned. Both are vectors, but the black part is part of an (flattened) icon.

[image]

How do I achieve this in Figma (through plugins or natively)?

Comment: Hi. I dont think there is a way to do this automatically in Figma. However, it would be possible to take a screenshot and measure the angle using other software such as GIMP or Photoshop, which both have a measure/ruler tool that can display the angle. Then you could rotate the object in Figma to the exact value measured.  For example in GIMP, I get 39.7° - if using this in Figma, you need to type in -39.7

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @Billy Kerr's answer, there is no way to achieve this directly.

But the other way to manipulate this would be using a pen tool in Figma.
Simply draw that shape using `pen tool` and give a fill to it.

Reference:

[image: Video]